# moment estimation for weibull distribution

Tags: r

I would like to fit weibull parameter using "Method of moments estimation"(MME) in R. I know we can estimate these value with `fitdisr()` function in `MASS` package, but I want to know if there is function or package to calculate the parameter with MME.
for example I want to approximate MME with Monte carlo Method. When I generate 1000 value from uniform distribution, the function that I write for this problem(for estimate of an integral), give me the 0 value. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: this is a "give me the code" question ... if you look up the mean and variance of the Weibull distribution, you can use a 2-dimensional root-finder to solve (mean,variance)=(shape,scale) (I think you could do a little bit of algebra to reduce the problem to a slightly simpler form where you might be able to do 1D root-finding, which is much easier)

Comment: thank you @BenBolker, but it's not a simple root-finder for me cause each of two equation must be solve at numerical calculation and I don't know how to solve those equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to use MME for finding the parameters of a Weibull distribution.

```
# load packages
require(rootSolve)
# generate data
N <- 1000
shape <- 2
scale <- 6
X <- rweibull(n=N, shape=shape, scale=scale)
# range of plausible shapes (for solver)
min_shape <- 0.1
max_shape <- 100 
# bootstraping
Nboot <- 1000
sim <- replicate(Nboot, {
  Xboot <- sample(X, replace=TRUE)
  # find shape
  rt <- 1+(sd(Xboot)/mean(Xboot))^2
  rootFct <- function(k) {
    gamma(1+2/k)/gamma(1+1/k)^2 - rt
  }
  shape_est <- uniroot.all(rootFct, c(min_shape, max_shape))
  if (length(shape_est)!=1) stop("The shape may be outside min_shape and max_shape")
  scale_est <- mean(Xboot)/gamma(1+1/shape_est)
  c(shape=shape_est, scale=scale_est)
})
apply(sim, 1, function(x)
  c(est=mean(x), se=sd(x), quantile(x, c(.025, .5, .975))))
```